# Moving elements in a list to the last

Tags: python

I'm trying to move elements in a list such that the first two elements will always be appended to the last in reverse order until the list is the same one I started with. For example for

```py
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I should get

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[3,4,5,2,1]
[5,2,1,4,3]
[1,4,3,2,5]
[3,2,5,4,1]
[5,4,1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

so six iterations will do.

Currently I have the following code

```py
l = [1,2,3,4,5] 
for i, j in zip(l, l[1:]): 
   l.append(l.pop(l.index(j)))  
   l.append(l.pop(l.index(i)))
```

What I was trying to do was to loop two consecutive elements and pop them and append to them as last two in the list in reversed order. This doesn't seem to work since printing the list at each step returns

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
[4, 5, 1, 3, 2]
[5, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

so only the first iteration seems to work. What should I modify here?

Comment: Why not just use `l.pop(1)` to remove the 2nd item, then append it, then `l.pop(0)` to remove the first item, then append it? Rather than using `zip`.

Comment: are you interested in the counts of iteration needed or those modified lists?

Comment: @Vicrobot I am yes!

Comment: Do you need the lists or do you **only** need the number of iterations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = l.copy()

while True:
    l = l[2:] + [l[1], l[0]]
    print(l)
    if l == c:
        break
```

Comment: `l[:-2], l[-2:] = l[2:], l[:2:-1]` should work as well.

Comment: Also, when reverse is used `l = l[2:] + list(reversed(l[:2]))` then 2 could be set via param and function would be more universal when you need more than 2 elements. It also makes the code easier to read because it does what it says.

Comment: Yeah.. Actually there a lot of ways to do this =)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a direct way to compute the steps needed for n distinct values:

```
(n-1) * (n+1) // 4 if n % 2 else n
```

Demo comparing an actually-do-it solution with my formula solution:

```
def naive_count(n):
    initial = list(range(n))
    a = initial.copy()
    steps = 0
    while True:
        a = a[2:] + a[1::-1]
        steps += 1
        if a == initial:
            return steps

def compute_count(n):
    return (n-1) * (n+1) // 4 if n % 2 else n

for n in range(2, 14):
    print(f'{n=}:', naive_count(n), compute_count(n))
```

Output:

```
n=2: 2 2
n=3: 2 2
n=4: 4 4
n=5: 6 6
n=6: 6 6
n=7: 12 12
n=8: 8 8
n=9: 20 20
n=10: 10 10
n=11: 30 30
n=12: 12 12
n=13: 42 42
```

And some larger ones:

```
for n in range(100, 110):
    print(f'{n=}:', naive_count(n), compute_count(n))
```

```
n=100: 100 100
n=101: 2550 2550
n=102: 102 102
n=103: 2652 2652
n=104: 104 104
n=105: 2756 2756
n=106: 106 106
n=107: 2862 2862
n=108: 108 108
n=109: 2970 2970
```

And a larger check:

```
print(all(naive_count(n) == compute_count(n)
          for n in range(2, 400)))
```

```
True
```

But don't expect me to explain the formula for odd n :-P

Comment: Well if someone is interested for even n the numbers will return to their positions at every floor(n/2) step. For odd the numbers will return at every floor(n/2) + 1 step, hence the numbers will return to the initial position at every floor(n/2)(floor(n/2) + 1) step. Although quite impressive how you came up with it! I assume you just computed them by hand to find this?

Comment: @Nate Yeah, even n is simple and I kinda noticed that for odd n after I posted this, but was too lazy to think it through. Didn't compute by hand, of course, but wrote the `naive_count` first and then looked at the outputs :-)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it with `append()` and `pop()`:

```py
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
newls = ls[2:] + [ls[1], ls[0]]

while newls != ls:
    newls.append(newls.pop(1))
    newls.append(newls.pop(0))
    print(newls)
```

Comment: Not just easy but also fast. But that extra first step before the loop isn't nice.

Comment: Yeah but necessary because there is no `do... while()` in python :/ There has to be a better way to do a similar thing though, I just didn't bother too much

Comment: I'd do it like the top answer does.